# THREE.js: Caustic mapping

Tags: three.js, webgl

I would like to implement [Caustic Mapping](http://graphics.cs.ucf.edu/old/caustics/caustics.pdf) (or any other fast caustics approximation method) in Three.js. More specifically, I want to simulate the effects of light shining through arbitrary meshes of a glass like material ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILET8tRcmIo)).

I've seen a few examples in Three.js and/or webgl space (Most notably [this](http://threejs-water.sydneyzh.com/)) although mostly with water and planer surfaces. I'm looking for a more general solution.

Before I deep dive and attempt to build the custom shaders, has there been any effort to do something similar in three.js? If not, would appreciate any implementation pointers.

Comment: What do you mean by "generalized solution"? The first one you linked to is entirely fake. It's just some animated texture being applied to everything. The second one is actually computing realtime caustics from the simulated waves. What's your goal? Most games just fake it like the first one although probably using projection mapping instead of whatever mapping that one is using)

Comment: @gman Thanks for your feedback, I updated the question to be more specific. I'm pretty new to the world of computer graphics so pardon my noobness. P.S, webgl2fundamentals looks great, it's on my reading list now :)